# user is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported

Tags: system, user, sudo

I have tried creating a user through command line with `sudo adduser user` but when I log in using that user's credential I get some error saying user is not in *sudoers* file. How can I add new user to *sudoers* file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I add new user to sudoers file?

If you wish to create a user with sudo privilege, execute,

```
sudo adduser --ingroup sudo <username>
```

If you wish to add an existing user, execute

```
sudo usermod -aG sudo <username>
```